# Realtek audio card not recognized and low volume

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

I'm having some audio issues (very low audio), so I tried to reinstall alsa audio tools and compile the source, when I got this [compiling error](https://ibb.co/bW9wTa).

I noticed that the Realtek audio card is not recognizable. On Windows, sound is good and Realtek  audio card is recognized, and I'm using dual boot.

The resault of sudo lshw -C sound

`*-multimedia:0

       description: Audio device
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:c2610000-c2613fff
  *-usb:0
       description: Video
       product: Lenovo EasyCamera
       vendor: Lenovo EasyCamera
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@3:1
       version: 12.28
       serial: Lenovo EasyCamera
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia:1
       description: Audio device
       product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:c2614000-c2617fff`

 resault of amixer controls:

`numid=1,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'
numid=7,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'
numid=13,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=8 Jack'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=1
numid=14,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=2
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'
numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=1
numid=15,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=2
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=1
numid=16,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=2
numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'
numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=1
numid=17,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=2
numid=6,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3
numid=19,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3
numid=12,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=7
numid=20,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=7
numid=18,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=8
numid=21,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=8`

The version of Ubuntu is Ubuntu Zesty

Thanks

Comment: Marco, put the output of these commands: `lshw -C sound` and `amixer controls` at your question, please.

Comment: First, open `alsamixer` at terminal session, press F6 to switch your devices and check volume level of each one. Maybe some of them is not properly raised.

Comment: this are the two card that alsamixer recognize                
    https://ibb.co/gqZ2Ja https://ibb.co/jEteya

Comment: Look, your master output is not 100% and you have 2(Speaker and PCM) that is unbalanced. You can install `pavucontrol` to manage it. By there, you can bind stereo to work together.